# Javascript collapsing ATOM nodes when parsing

Tags: javascript, atom-feed

I am reading an ATOM feed with jQuery and looping over the results. While doing this jQuery seems to be collapsing two nodes into one.

ATOM:

```
   <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://twitter.com/leesalove/statuses/34751066604044288" />
   <link rel="image" type="image/png" href="http://a1.twimg.com/profile_images/1236597389    ge_normal.jpg" />
```

BECOMES

```
, link : 'http://twitter.com/leesalove/statuses/34751066604044288'
```

So the second value is lost. Problem I, that's the one I need.

Here is how I am loading the data. Having to use the Google Feed Proxy because it's coming from a different domain then the host.

```
    var url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&q=' + escape('http://vivaglam.tidytweet.com/VivaGlam.atom');

    jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){
        if (data.responseStatus == 200) {
            jQuery(data.responseData.feed.entries).each(function(i,p) {
                console.log(p);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Care to show how you load it and try to access it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you read the contents (*which might be were the problem is, but without a sample of your code we cannot tell*), but you can use JSONP instead of atom which is javascript friendly :)

```
var url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3Aleesalove&rpp=100&callback=?';

$.getJSON(url, function(data){
    // do what you want with results here..
    // data.total is the count
    // data.results is a list of the results
});
```

the documentation for the api is at http://search.twitter.com/api/

---

**Update**

I see, you are using the google feed api.
If you stare at the [specification](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/jsondevguide.html#resultJson) they show (*with the lack of* **[ ]**) that it returns a single value.

And i believe the one they pick is not based on index (*the first*) but the one with `rel="alternate"` since that is supposed to give you the link to the article..

You can use the xml version (*also returned through json*) which returns all elements.
To do this you need to add to your url another parameter [`&output=xml`<sup>doc</sup>](http://code.google.com/apis/feed/v1/jsondevguide.html#optArgs).

You can use jQuery to read the xml and traverse it.

```
   var url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=?&output=xml&q=' + escape('http://vivaglam.tidytweet.com/VivaGlam.atom');

    jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data){
        if (data.responseStatus == 200) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data.responseData.xmlString);
            var $xml = $(xmlDoc);

            $xml.find('entry').each(function(i,p) {
                console.log( $(p).find('link[rel="image"]').attr('href') );
            });
        }
    });
```

Demo at : http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/vANcv/
(*uses jquery 1.5 for the [`$.parseXML`<sup>doc</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), but it would be the same if you just `$(xmlstring)`*)

Comment: Added code sample. Unfortunately it has to remain ATOM because the moderation tool I am using only allows this format.

Comment: Like a charm. You have been a tremendous help. Thanks so much.

Comment: This is most wonderful!  A javascript novice, was looking for something helpful.